# Set style dynamically in even-odd rows?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I have a table with 2 cols and N rows, im setting a center line by drawing the right border of left cols, and left border of right cols.

Im calling css with the :nth-child rule to do it, but now i need to set dynamically the color of the border, so i wont be able to do that through the css file.

Some idea about how to solve this in another way?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can still use CSS, but you'll need a bit of Lightning expressions as well. Here's a simple demo:

## CSS

```
.THIS .red-border {
    border-color: red;
}
.THIS .green-border {
    border-color: green;
}
.THIS .blue-border {
    border-color: blue;
}
.THIS .gray-border {
    border-color: gray;
}
.THIS .demo div:nth-child(even) {
    border-left-width: 7px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.THIS .demo div:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right-width: 7px;
    border-right-style: solid;
}
```

## Application/Component

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3"></div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-grid demo slds-wrap">
                <div class="red-border slds-size_1-of-2">This is red</div>
                <div class="blue-border slds-size_1-of-2">This is blue</div>
                <div class="green-border slds-size_1-of-2">This is green</div>
                <div class="gray-border slds-size_1-of-2">This is gray</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3"></div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

---

Resulting output:

[image: Demo of CSS above]

Note that this is, of course, static. What you need is to express the style dynamically:

```
<div class="{!item.borderColor + ' slds-size_1-of-2'}"> ...
```

This works because style rules are cumulative, so you can specify a border in one rule and a color in another, and they'll combine.